# Executing cypher query in graphdb

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am very new to graph db. I am trying to get a sample result based on the following program. but i don't know what's the error. It's obviously showing no error but it stops after executing

engine created

I don't know what went wrong.Please help me to fix this .Is there any problem with the jars I included. Can anyone specify which all I have to include just to make sure that I did the right thing.

```
    RestAPI api = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/");
    System.out.println("API created");
    final RestCypherQueryEngine engine = new RestCypherQueryEngine(api);
    System.out.println("engine created");
QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("start n=node({id}) return n", map("id",1));

    System.out.println("query created");
    System.out.println(result);


for (Map<String, Object> row : result) 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Object tagline = row.get("tagline");
    long id=((Number)row.get("id")).longValue();
    System.out.println("id is " + id);
    System.out.println(row.get("myRow"));
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about neo4j-rest-graphdb-1.9.M04.jar ?

Comment: Can you write Neo4J version together with the library you are using in Java?

Comment: @TBM I included that but still no luck after showing upto "engine created" it stops.. Plz help me

Comment: @MarcoCI i didn't get u..are u telling that instead of specifying http://localhost:7474/ I have to write this /home/surya/Documents/softwares/neo4j-community-2.0.1

Comment: You probably shouldn't use java-rest-bindings built for Neo4j 1.9 with Neo4j 2.0.1. Have you tried https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/tree/neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.1? Also, check the server log files, `graph.db/messages.log` and the ones in `log/` directory.

Comment: No, just asking for versions of library and tools you are using: using mismatching versions is a common error.

Answer (score 0):

The java-rest-bindings library is not a very good tool for talking to the Neo4j Server. You would be better served using the Neo4j JDBC driver, which supports the latest transactional features in the 2.x series.

You can find it here:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc

And it is used like the regular JDBC API, see the JDBC API docs for reference. You connect using a neo4j connection string, like so:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/");
```